# Symfony3: Binding Form to Entity Classes

Tags: php, forms, symfony, orm, frameworks

I'm creating a form using built-in Symfony3 services:
1) creating new class in `AppBundle\Form` which extends `AbstractType`
2) creating a form object in my controller (using `createForm()`)
3) pushing that object directly to twig layer (by `createView()`)

In my Entities direction I've got two classes, already mapped to database by ORM.
First one is `User`, and the second one is `UserAttribute`. `User` is related to `UserAttribute` by OneToMany annotation. Relationship looks like:

```php
class UserAttr
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="userAttr" )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;
```

And from the `User` side:

```php
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserAttr", mappedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $userAttr;
```

When I'm adding new fields (using `$builder->add()`) everything works fine if they are associated to `User` class properties. But if I'm doing the same with `UserAttribute` properties - symfony can't find get/set methods for that properties. I know - I can fix it by `class User extends UserAttribute` but probably that's not the point. Symfony must have another solution for that, probably I missed something.

Thanks for your time !

```php
// SOLVED | there should be defined an EntityClassType as below:
$builder->add('credit',EntityType::class,array(
                'class' => UserAttr::class
            ));
```

Comment: How is your relationship? Many `User` associated with a single `UserAttribute` or vice versa?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, i made few changes in my code and updated it above. Now i've got : User--->OneToMany--->UserAttr, and inversed side UserAttr--->ManyToOne--->User

Comment: Do you want to add / modify number of associated `UserAttr` properties from user form ?

Comment: Not exactly, I just want to add new field called credit in my form (this is `UserAttr` property, not `User` ). I can render that form with added 'credit' field, but after submitting it appears new error: 
`Neither the property "credit" nor one of the methods "getCredit()", "credit()", "isCredit()", "hasCredit()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\User".`

Comment: Thanks for your time Jeet, i found the solution and already updated my post above.

Answer (score 0):

You have `One-To-Many` Association to `UserAttr` from `User` Entity. Hence, A User might have multiple credit.

**OPTION 1 :**

Considering this, you have to use a `collection` field type in UserFormType, which is a bit lengthy process.

```
$builder->add('userAttr', CollectionType::class, array(
    'label' => false,
    'allow_add' => true,
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'entry_type' => UserAttrType::class
));
```

Then create another FormType : `UserAttrType` to represent `UserAttr` where you can have the `credit` field as a property from `UserAttr`.

```
$builder
    ->add('credit', TextType::class, array(
        'label' => 'Credit',
    ))
```

This way, The form will load and submit accordingly, The credit value will also be updated when User form gets updated. Here is a link for [collection docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html). This is how to [embed a collection form](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html).

**OPTION 2 :**

But, If you want to simplify it further, add `mapped = false` ([doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped)) to the `credit` field. This will ignore the current error. However, you have to manually collect the `credit` value from `Form` Object and set  value to appropriate `UserAttr` Object in Submit Handler.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, but given error is telling us about something different. There is no issue due to collection type, otherwise it should suggest me to implement `__toString()` method or something different. Even if I change relationship from ManyToOne/OneToMany to OneToOne the error still appears.

Comment: Yeah, That is usual. All you have to do is add a `__toString()` magic function in `UserAttr` and return any property to identify it. may be `credit`.

Comment: Jeet, I wrote before that the given error occurs because Symfony doesn't see a getCredit() method. When i want to `if ($form->isSubmited()){
dump($form->getData()}`  in my controller function symfony is trying to find the `getCredit()` method and couldnt. Thats happens because that method is out of `User` class (is implemented in `UserAttr` class). The question is - How can I solve it without adding `class User extends UserAttr`. I am watching another tutorial, and there is implemented it without `extends` but i cant figure it out how its done.